# Fields of finite characteristic are not axiomatizable.

Tags: logic, model-theory

"Prove that fields of finite characteristic are not axiomatizable by the 1st order theory."
How to prove this statement?

Characteristic is a smallest number of units such that it's sum is equal to zero.

I found similar theorems in "Handbook of Mathematical Logic" by Jon Barwise. (1st book, "Model Theory", page 16.)

But it's a complicated question for me, I didn't manage to catch an analogy with torsion-free groups.

There is a formula in "weak second order logic":
$$\exists n\geqslant 1. \,[n1=0],$$
where $n1:=\underbrace{1+...+1}_{n \text{ times}}$.

I can axiomatize fields of zero characteristic.
That is just axioms of fields plus infinite many of such axioms:
$1+1\neq 0, 1+1+1\neq 0, 1+1+1+1\neq 0, \dots .$

Comment: What is your question? How to prove? Use *ultraproduct*.

Comment: @Berci , Yes. I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Do you know the compactness theorem? What does it say? Can you think of a way to use it here?

Comment: Assume for a contradiction that $T$ is a set of axioms for fields of finite characteristic. Is $T$ consistent with any finite sobset of your axioms for characteristic zero?

Comment: @bof, Yes, I know the proof of compactness theorem. Now i think about your next comment.

Comment: T0 is theory for zero characteristic. Every finite subset of T0 has model by compactness. Assume that T is a theory of finite fields. Then every finite subtheory has model. No, T is not consistent with any subset, because there exist a axiom number n+x (x is a number of axioms of any field) which says that not(n1=0), which is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, toward a contradiction, that $T$ were a theory whose models are exactly the fields of finite characteristic. Let $Z$ be the set of axioms you gave for "characteristic $0$". So $T\cup Z$ has no models. Therefore, by compactness, there are finite subsets $T_0\subseteq T$ and $Z_0\subseteq Z$ such that $T_0\cup Z_0$ has no models. Since $Z_0$ is finite, let $p$ be a prime number greater than all the $n$'s for which $Z_0$ contains the sentence $1+1+\cdots+1=0$ with $n$ $1$'s. Then all the sentences in $Z_0$ are true in the finite field $\mathbb Z/p$. All the sentences of $T_0$ (and in fact all the sentences of $T$) are also true in $\mathbb Z/p$ because this is a field of finite characteristic. So $\mathbb Z/p$ is a model of $T_0\cup Z_0$; contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal U$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, i.e. no finite set belongs to $\mathcal U$, and consider
$$M:=\prod_n\Bbb F_{p_n}/\mathcal U$$
where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime and $\Bbb F_p$ is the field of $p$ elements.
Now, if $T$ is a theory of fields such that each $\Bbb F_p$ is its model, then so is $M$, while the characteristic of $M$ *is zero*, because for any prime $q$, except for finitely many (namely, one) $p$, all $\Bbb F_p\models \overbrace{1+\dots+1}^q\ne 0$, hence it also holds in $M$.